# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". Java Application Error

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing server side socket application using Java, but I have no idea what can cause this error

> ```
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
> ```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this message because slf4j could not find a binding in your classpath. slf4j is like a wrapper over other logging frameworks. It needs the binding library of the logging framework you intend to use to actually log the messages. e.g., for using log4j, add the libraries slf4j-log4j12.jar and log4j.jar.
More details can be found in the SLF4J manual at http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html.

> To switch logging frameworks, just replace slf4j bindings on your
> class path. For example, to switch from java.util.logging to log4j,
> just replace slf4j-jdk14-1.7.10.jar with slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar.
>
> SLF4J does not rely on any special class loader machinery. In fact,
> each SLF4J binding is hardwired at compile time to use one and only
> one specific logging framework. For example, the
> slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar binding is bound at compile time to use
> log4j. In your code, in addition to slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar, you simply
> drop one and only one binding of your choice onto the appropriate
> class path location. Do not place more than one binding on your class
> path.

Comment: The binding tells sl4j which library(log4j, java logging etc) to use for logging. There should be only one binding library in the classpath.

Comment: The binding library is used by sl4j to connect to the actual logging framework.